# All possible combinations over groups

Tags: r, combinatorics

I have 5 groups: G1, G2,…,G5 with n1,n2,…,n5 elements in each group respectively. I select 2 elements from each of the 4 groups and 1 element from the 5th group. How do I generate all possible combinations in R?

Comment: Look at `?combn` and `?expand.grid`. Other than that, try to provide a *real* data set and desired output

Comment: Are your groups mutually exclusive or not? i.e. Can the groups have same elements with the other groups? Please specify. If they are mut. exc. then we can assign numbers to the group elements and try to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(It is not specified in the question whether the groups are mutually exclusive or not; So, assume:
**1.** the groups are mutually exclusive
**2.** the subsets of groups (n1, n2, ...) will use the same elements in being filled)
**3** just for the sake of argument |G1|=|G2|=|G3|=5 (The user can change the following code accordingly for differing numbers of elements in the groups)
The following is 3 set mock-up answer of the question that any user can generalize to arbitrary number of groups. So, assume group names are G1, G2, G3.

```
library(causfinder)
gctemplate(5,2,2) # Elements are coded as: 1,2,3,4,5; |sub-G1|=2; |sub-G2|=2; |sub-G3|=5-(2+2)=1
# In the following table, each number represents a unique element. (SOLUTION ENDED!)
```

My package (causfinder) is not in CRAN. Hence, I will give the function gctemplate's code below.

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
 [1,]    1    2    3    4    5   sub-G1={1,2}  sub-G2={3,4} sub-G3={5}
 [2,]    1    2    3    5    4
 [3,]    1    2    4    5    3   sub-G1={1,2}  sub-G2={4,5} sub-G3={3}
 [4,]    1    3    2    4    5
 [5,]    1    3    2    5    4
 [6,]    1    3    4    5    2
 [7,]    1    4    2    3    5
 [8,]    1    4    2    5    3
 [9,]    1    4    3    5    2
[10,]    1    5    2    3    4
[11,]    1    5    2    4    3
[12,]    1    5    3    4    2
[13,]    2    3    1    4    5
[14,]    2    3    1    5    4
[15,]    2    3    4    5    1
[16,]    2    4    1    3    5
[17,]    2    4    1    5    3
[18,]    2    4    3    5    1
[19,]    2    5    1    3    4
[20,]    2    5    1    4    3
[21,]    2    5    3    4    1
[22,]    3    4    1    2    5
[23,]    3    4    1    5    2
[24,]    3    4    2    5    1
[25,]    3    5    1    2    4
[26,]    3    5    1    4    2
[27,]    3    5    2    4    1
[28,]    4    5    1    2    3
[29,]    4    5    1    3    2
[30,]    4    5    2    3    1
```

The code of gctemplate:

```
gctemplate <- function(nvars, ncausers, ndependents){
independents <- combn(nvars, ncausers)
patinajnumber <-  dim(combn(nvars - ncausers, ndependents))[[2]]
independentspatinajednumber <- dim(combn(nvars, ncausers))[[2]]*patinajnumber 
dependents <- matrix(, nrow = dim(combn(nvars, ncausers))[[2]]*patinajnumber, ncol = ndependents)
for (i in as.integer(1:dim(combn(nvars, ncausers))[[2]])){   
dependents[(patinajnumber*(i-1)+1):(patinajnumber*i),] <- t(combn(setdiff(seq(1:nvars), independents[,i]), ndependents))
}
independentspatinajed <- matrix(, nrow = dim(combn(nvars, ncausers))[[2]]*patinajnumber, ncol = ncausers)
for (i in as.integer(1:dim(combn(nvars, ncausers))[[2]])){   
for (j in as.integer(1:patinajnumber)){   
independentspatinajed[(i-1)*patinajnumber+j,] <- independents[,i]  
}}
independentsdependents <- cbind(independentspatinajed, dependents)
others <- matrix(, nrow = dim(combn(nvars, ncausers))[[2]]*patinajnumber, ncol = nvars - ncausers - ndependents) 
for (i in as.integer(1:((dim(combn(nvars, ncausers))[[2]])*patinajnumber))){  
others[i, ]  <- setdiff(seq(1:nvars), independentsdependents[i,]) 
}
causalitiestemplate <- cbind(independentsdependents, others)
causalitiestemplate
}
```

Now, the solution for G1,G2,G3 is the above. Just generalize the above code to 5-variable case with the very same logic!